# getbounds in Flutter google maps plugin

Tags: android, mobile, flutter

i need to  get all the markers on the screen i searching and i find methods in javascript and java using getBounds is any way to do this in  flutter?

```
var markers; // your markers
var map; // your map
for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++){
    if( map.getBounds().contains(markers[i].getPosition()) ){
    // code for showing your object, associated with markers[i]
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Am assuming the markers were added into the map from a list.
By getting the list (that has properties of the markers you get the list).

```
var markers ;//equals all the markers.
```